# Lookup based on input field via returned value from function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

(rewriting the question)

An input field in a form has an item stock number. I need to get a meta value from an external site based on that item stock number.

Assume that the external site's page for that stock number has a meta value

```
<meta description="Widget Part Red">
```

And the item stock number is '12345'.

And that the external URL is https://www.example.com/12345

The input field in the form is similar to

```
<input name='stocknumber' id='stocknumber' onblur='getitemdesc();'>
```

And the item description will be placed in this span

```
<span id='thedescription'></span>
```

And the script has

```
function getitemdesc() {
    // get the value from the input field
    var itemnumber=$('input[name="stocknumber"]').val;
    // some process/function to query the external url and get the meta:description value from the page
    var metadesc = someprocess_to_return_meta_desc;
    // that process/function returns 'metadesc'
    // and inserting the metadesc into the span
      $("#thedescription").html(metadesc);  
}
```

What is the best way to get the meta value from the external URL and return it to the function so that I can put the meta:description into the span?

(Assume proper sanitization of the input fields.)

Comment: You need to add parenthesis to `var itemnumber=$('input[name="stocknumber"]').val;` like so `var itemnumber=$('input[name="stocknumber"]').val()`;

Answer (score 0):

it seems you should use VALUE rather TEXT like:

```
$('#countryname').val(thecountryname);
```

everything else seems to be ok

See demo [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/fdtbzr3o/)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to `fetch` the page and use a regular expression to extract the content of the meta description. It seems a bit weird to do that to be honest and you might run into CORS issues.

A better solution would be to send a request to your server to extract the meta header from the page.

```js
fetch('https://example.com/items/123456')
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(text => text.match(/<meta description="([^"]+)">/i))
  .then(meta => {
    // meta is null if there's no match and otherwise meta[1] will contain the item description.
    if(meta) {
      $('#thedescription').html(meta[1]);
    }
  })
```

Comment: Note that example.com is not my server. It is another server. I need to get the meta from an external (not-my-server) page.

Comment: This piece of code will do exactly that. In this example, example.com is your distant server.

But as I said, you might run into CORS issues and so the best solution is to let the back-end code request the page, parse the description out and output it.